# Continually trying to reconnect until a connection is established

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm trying to create a routine which does the following

```
while(true)
{

  cxn = connect(addr);
  if(!cxn)
  {
    sleep(1000);
    continue;
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

However, due to the asynchronous nature of the NodeJS and the websocket library I am using (ws), it appears that I am forced to use callbacks for detecting a successful connection vs an error.  I can't figure out how to adapt this to my algorithm above because the event of a successful connection vs failed is assumed to occur within the loop and not be bound to an asynchronous function.

Here is an example of what I mean to illustrate the point I am trying to make:

```
while(true)
{

  cxn = connect(addr);
  cxn.on('error', function(error)
  {
    sleep(1000);
    continue; // this is invalid
  });
  cxn.on('connect', function()
  {
    break; // this is invalid
  });
}
```

As you can see here.  Both the *continue* and *break* statements are invalid because they occur within the bounds of a callback function which isn't called inside the bounds of a for loop.

How would I go about implementing this desired functionality given the asynchronous design of Node and WS?

**EDIT: ** I have tried to modify my code to make it block until a connection is established.  However, I am still unable to get a connection and the program just hangs.  I would assume that my *while* loop is somehow blocking execution of the event loop.  Any ideas?

Code:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var socket = null;

function try_connection(addr)
{
  var connection_status = 'CONNECTING';
  console.log("attempting to connect to web socket server...");
  socket = new WebSocket(addr);
  socket.on('error', function(error)
  {
    if(error.errno == 'ECONNREFUSED')
    {
      console.log('CONNREFUSED');
      debugger;
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('unrecoverable error...');
      process.exit(-1);
    }
  });

  socket.on('open', function()
  {
    console.log('connection opened');
    debugger;
    connection_status = 'CONNECTED';
  });

  while(connection_status != 'CONNECTED')
  {
    setTimeout(100);
    continue;
  }
  return socket;
}

try_connection('ws://127.0.0.1:1337');
console.log('hello world');
```

Comment: As far as I know the design advice in asynchronous JS (from for example w3schools) is to implement the resulting calls also in your asynchronous part: So at the place where you capture the connect, you release the use of all your other functions. IE: It renders your asynchronous use useless most of the time.....

Comment: Yes, but then in order to retry a new connection, I would have to nest the connect code within within the error block.  I feel like the best way to go about this would be to implement it as a recursive function.  It just seems really weird to have to do this for such a simple routine.

Comment: Hence the remark I made on this design model:  IE: It renders your asynchronous use useless most of the time.....

To break your loop you could check you connection in the while:
while(true) would become while(!cxn.somecheck)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with an asynchronous "recursive" function:

```
function tryConnecting(callback) {
  var cxn = connect(addr);
  cxn.on('error', function(error) {
    setTimeout(tryConnecting.bind(this, callback), 1000);
  });
  cxn.on('connect', function() {
    callback(cxn);
  });
}
```

`tryConnecting` calls itself repeatedly, in one-second intervals (using `setTimeout`), until the `connect()` call causes the `connect` event to fire. When it does, instead of queuing up another `setTimeout` call to run `tryConnecting`, the `callback` function runs with `cxn` as its argument.

Anything you want to do after the connection completes should go inside of the `callback` function you pass into `tryConnecting`.

Comment: Won't this eventually eat up all the memory on the stack?  Is there not a better solution?

Comment: @user3285713 - This isn't the classic recursion.  Because the events are asynchronous, the stack is completely unwound between each call and there is no stack build-up.  This is a typical design pattern for dealing with retrying an operation that fails asynchronously (e.g. sometime later) in Javascript.

Comment: @user3285713 `setTimeout` queues up a function to be called at some point in the future. The stack fully clears before that invocation happens, so there is no ever-climbing memory increase.